# Quero abrir dois menus distintos na minha aplicação?

Tags: react, react-native, react-navigation

Tenho um `tab` que abre a minha gaveta:

```js
<Tab NavMenu={() => this.props.navigation.openDrawer()}
     NavProfile={() => this.toggleOpenProfile()} 
/>
```

Na minha navegação está assim

```js
const AppDrawer = createDrawerNavigator(
{
    App: AppStack
},
{
    contentComponent: MenuComponent,
        drawerWidth: 290,
    },
);

const Navigator = createSwitchNavigator(
{
    AuthLoading: AuthLoadingScreen,
    App: AppDrawer,
    Auth: AuthStack,
},
{
    initialRouteName: 'AuthLoading',
});
```

Quando clicar no meu `profile`, eu quero abrir um novo tipo de menu isso é possível?

Comment: Sim é possível, mas, o problema da sua pergunta que você deveria ter colocado um exemplo minimo só com esses códigos fica complicado dizer qualquer resposta ... Monte um mini exemplo e [edite a sua pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/407915/edit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer, createSwitchNavigator, createDrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

import LoginScreen from './screens/LoginScreen';
import RegisterScreen from './screens/RegisterScreen';
import HomeScreen from './screens/HomeScreen';
import MenuScreen from './screens/MenuScreen';
import ProfileScreen from './screens/ProfileScreen';
import PostScreen from './screens/PostScreen';
import MenuComponent from './components/MenuComponent';
import ProfileComponent from './components/ProfileComponent';

import AuthLoadingScreen from './utils/AuthLoading';

// Screens when user is logged
const AppStack = createStackNavigator(
    {
        Home: HomeScreen,
        Menu: MenuScreen,
        Post: PostScreen,
    },
    {
        headerMode: 'none',
        navigationOptions: {
            headerVisible: false,
        },
    }
);
const AppProfile = createStackNavigator(
    {
        Profile: ProfileScreen,
    },
    {
        headerMode: 'none',
        navigationOptions: {
            headerVisible: false,
        },
    }
);

// Screens when user is not logged
const AuthStack = createStackNavigator(
    {
        Login: LoginScreen,
        Register: RegisterScreen,
    },
    {
        headerMode: 'none',
        navigationOptions: {
            headerVisible: false,
        },
    }
);

const AppDrawer = createDrawerNavigator(
    {
        App: AppStack
    },
    {
        contentComponent: MenuComponent,
        drawerWidth: 290,
    },
);

const ProfileDrawer = createDrawerNavigator(
    {
        App: AppProfile
    },
    {
        contentComponent: ProfileComponent,
        drawerWidth: 290,
    },
);

const Navigator = createSwitchNavigator(
    {
        AuthLoading: AuthLoadingScreen,
        App: AppDrawer,
        Auth: AuthStack,
        App2: ProfileDrawer,
    },
    {
        initialRouteName: 'AuthLoading',
    }
);

export default Navigator;
```